# Finding any $\delta$ that $||(y,s)-(x,t)||<\delta$ implies $s<||y||$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

I want to show that the set

$$S=\{(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\;|\;\;t<||x||\}$$
 is an open set. Let $(x,t)\in S$, so we have $t<||x||$.

So we have to show that 
$$B((x,t);\delta)=\{(y,s)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\;|\;||(y,s)-(x,t)||<\delta\}\subset S$$
So we need to show that if $||(y,s)-(x,t)||<\delta$, then $s<||y||$ and so $B((x,t);\delta)\subset S$, I tried to find such $\delta$ and couldn't find it. Please help me.

Comment: is the answer not sufficient enough?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Now, your answer is sufficient enough for me!

Comment: what happened? I didn't change anything. Or did you just realized something you haven't before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a different approach:

The function $f(x,t)= t-\|x\|$ is continuous. Thus $f^{-1}((-\infty,0))=S$ is open (since the preimage of an open set of a continuous function is open)